# Why is the last element of the array skipped by the useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm just studying React and in particular I'm studying the useEffect.

What I'm failing to figure out is why the useEffect is skipping me the last element of the array.

Can someone kindly explain to me why and how to fix it please?

```
let users = ['Oliver', 'Thomas', 'George', 'William']
export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  console.log('RENDER');
  useEffect(() => {
    if (index === users.length - 1) {
      return
    }
    setTimeout(() => setIndex(index => index + 1), 2000)
    console.log('Hello ' + users[index]);
    console.log('Side Effect RUNS!');
  }, [users[index]])

}
```

Comment: Well you have `if (index === users.length - 1) return` which literally says "if this is the index of the last element of the array, skip it". Perhaps you meant `index > users.length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you made a condition to return in useEffect, if the index is equal to the last element index:

```js
if (index === users.length - 1) {
    return
}
```

You need to make the if statement condition to return,  if the index is greater than the last element index:

```js
// users.length equals (element last index + 1), since the first array index is 0
if (index === users.length) {
    return;
}
```

This will make the function work.

One last thing is that you need to clear the timeout to avoid memory leaks, and it may give you unexpected results sometimes.

Here is the full code:

```js
  let users = ['Oliver', 'Thomas', 'George', 'William']
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  console.log('RENDER');
  useEffect(() => {

    // returning if we passed last array index
    if (index === users.length) {
      return
    }
    // we named out timeout to be able to clear it
    const timer = setTimeout(() => setIndex(index => index + 1), 2000)
    console.log('Hello ' + users[index]);
    console.log('Side Effect RUNS!');

    // clearing the timeout to avoid anyproblems
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }, [users[index]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

let users = ['Oliver', 'Thomas', 'George', 'George', 'William'];

export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  console.log('RENDER');
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Hello ' + users[index]);
    console.log('Side Effect RUNS!');

    if (index < users.length - 1) {
      let timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
        setIndex(preIndex => preIndex + 1);
      }, 1000);

      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timeOut); // Clean up the timeout on component unmount or re-render
      };
    }
  }, [index]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Index: {index}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `if (index === users.length - 1)` statement literally skips the last element.

You can simply make it `if (index >= users.length)`

Comment: No, it's not. Return in this line does nothing

Comment: Have you tried this locally? It does log the last user

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

because you return before you it you should  do

```
let users = ['Oliver', 'Thomas', 'George', 'William']
export default function App() {
 const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
 console.log('RENDER');
  useEffect(() => {

setTimeout(() => setIndex(index => index + 1), 2000)
console.log('Hello ' + users[index]);
console.log('Side Effect RUNS!');
if (index === users.length - 1) {
  return
}
 }, [users[index]])

}
```

or you should

```
if (index >= users.length)
```

for the xisting code

Comment: This return statement does nothing

Answer (score -2):

Your `useEffect` doesn't run because `users[index]` has the same value

Change it to `index`

```
let users = ['Oliver', 'Thomas', 'George', 'William']
export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  console.log('RENDER');
  useEffect(() => {
    if (index === users.length - 1) {
      return
    }
    setTimeout(() => setIndex(index => index + 1), 2000)
    console.log('Hello ' + users[index]);
    console.log('Side Effect RUNS!');
  }, [index]) // change to `[index]`

}
```